# Thead Datatables

Tags: codeigniter, datatable

I want to create a custom based on the number of dates in a month, is it possible to make thead in

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //datatables
    table = $('#table').DataTable({
});
```

Answer (score 0):

DataTable provide a [headerCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/headerCallback) hook to modify the header of your table.
For example if you want to show some information on the first header column, you could try it like :

```
table = $('#table').DataTable({
    headerCallback: function headerCallback(thead, data, start, end, display) {
        $(thead)
            .find('th')
            .first()
            .html('Sometext here');
    }
});
```